# Partial Dependency plots and Gradient boosting (GBM package)

Tags: r, gbm

Is it possible to plot a partial dependency plot to display the class probability and estimate the effects of a predictor for a [GBM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) model?
Something similar to `partialPlot` from `randomForest` package.

[image]

According to [this article](http://adventuresindm.blogspot.gr/2013/01/partial-dependency-plots-and-gbm.html), a partial plot is doable with gbm.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution,

In order to estimate the effects of a predictor, one should use this:

`plot(gbm.model, i.var = 1, lwd = 2, main = "")`

`i.var` is the number of the variable predictor, in the order shown in your formula.
E.g `y = x1+x2+x3`

Thanks to Mr. Campbell

Comment: you can also use `i="variable name"` if you want to use the actual variable name too